# How to add negative number to the end of rand function and send them into serial port

Tags: matlab

I need to create program which gives me 5 random numbers (from 0 to 9, integers). Then In second part I have to add at the end of those random numbers one negative in order from -1 to -5. And then send them via bluetooth to my arduino. I know how to solve the first step(5 random numbers) adn the last(write them via bluetooth). But for example when I have send these data 6 times. It has to look like this (negative numbers should go again from beginning).

```
7  8  1  8  6 -1
1  3  5  9  5 -2
5  6  7  1  2 -3
.             -4
.             -5
1  3  5  7  8 -1
```

Program which I use right now.
    clear all;
    clc;

```
b = Bluetooth('HC-05', 1);
fopen(b);

x = round(rand(1,5)*9);
a = num2str(x);        
    disp(x)

    fwrite(b,a);


    p = fscanf(b, '%s');
    disp(p);

fclose(b);
```

Comment: How does this differ from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766995/how-to-add-number-at-the-end-of-rand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to use `randi()` to generate your sequence instead:

```
x = [randi([0 9], 1, 5) randi([-5 -1])]; %//generate 1x5 vector of random int 0 to 9, and 1x1 value of random int -5 to -1
```

To generate `N` rows:

```
x=[]; neg = 0;
for a=1:N
   neg = neg - 1;
   if (neg < -5)
       neg = -1; %//wrap around
   end
   x = [x; [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg]]; %//add new row of random numbers to x
end
```

Comment: The negative numbers can't be random they have to be in order. As you can see in my example in the top. Also can I do that separetly? 1 step create random numbers and then in another step add negative number?

Comment: @Franta123456 yes, you can do it separately. Also I have edited the answer for the negative number :) hope it helps

Comment: Thank's a lot. And do you know where should I put fwrite function? I put it behind x = [x; [randi([0 9], 1, 5) neg]]; fwrite(b,x) and it sends me only 1 line not 5 then matlab show me error: An error occured during writing.

Comment: @Franta123456 About the writing part, that I'm not too sure.

Comment: I'll try create new question. But you really helped me.